# Analog sensor output incorrect when sensor not connected

Tags: analog, output

[image: schematic]
[image: pcb]

I created a simple circuit to measure an analogue photo detector output that has 3 pins (vcc, gnd, output).

I create a PCB by iron method to test it. But the problem is when the sensors are not connected to the board and the supply is connected, I measure the output pins of the sensor on the board with voltmeter (note that there are no sensor connect on board) it shows some voltage instead of zero volts.

The SENSOR1 shows 3.9V and the SENSOR2 shows 0.3V. (I used a 0/1 switch to control the supply and an LED to show the supply and also pull-down the outputs of sensors with 10k resistors.)

Please help me.
Sorry for my bad grammar and description.

Comment: There is a couple of oddities in this schematic, just looking at the power supply. Why's your 7805 decoupled by only 100p capacitors, and why do you have an LED right between the 5V rail and ground? I don't think the LED would be too happy about that.

Comment: it makes no sense to have an output terminal without a ground pin

Comment: @jsotola balanced output! checkmate!

Comment: "I create a PCB by iron method" - perhaps your board is contaminated. Try cleaning the board, especially between between the sensor connector pins.

Comment: @Richard the Spacecat    the  amount of capacitors is not important at this time. I put those capasitors as datasheet of the 7805 told. LED is just for showing off/on state of the switch and supply I also forgot to add resistor before LED.

Comment: @jsotola  but I measure the output terminal with voltmeter rather than ground.

Comment: I should mention that I tested this circuit on a bread board but there was no such problem with output. I mean the output was zero correctly.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I did your advice and it worked. Thank you.